# How to select a random URL form extracted URL list

Tags: python, random, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the proxy urls and would like to use one random url

```
import requests
from lxml import html
import random

def get_proxy():
    url = 'https://sslproxies.org/'
    req = requests.get(url)
    iptree = html.fromstring(req.content)
    iprange = range(1,20)
    for ips in iprange:
        https = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[7]//text()'%ips)
        iptd = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]//text()'%ips)
        port = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]//text()'%ips)
        for htp in https:
            if htp=="yes":
                for (ips, por) in zip(iptd, port):
                    iplist = ("https://" + ips + ":" + por)
                    print(iplist)

get_proxy()
```

i want to assign one random URL to a string and use it in my web scraper, but i am unable to select random one

Comment: `random.choice(iplist)`?

Comment: it is selecting random letters from urls but not whole url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_proxy():
    url = 'https://sslproxies.org/'
    req = requests.get(url)
    iptree = html.fromstring(req.content)
    iprange = range(1,20)
    iplist =[ ]
    for ips in iprange:
        https = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[7]//text()'%ips)
        iptd = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]//text()'%ips)
        port = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]//text()'%ips)
        for htp in https:
            if htp=="yes":
                for (ips, por) in zip(iptd, port):
                    ip = "https://" + ips + ":" + por
                    iplist.append(ip)
     return random.choice(iplist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from lxml import html
import random

def get_proxy():
    url = 'https://sslproxies.org/'
    req = requests.get(url)
    iptree = html.fromstring(req.content)
    iprange = range(1,20)
    iplist = []
    for ips in iprange:
        https = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[7]//text()'%ips)
        iptd = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[1]//text()'%ips)
        port = iptree.xpath('//*[@id="proxylisttable"]/tbody/tr[%d]/td[2]//text()'%ips)
        for htp in https:
            if htp=="yes":
                for (ips, por) in zip(iptd, port):
                    ip = ("https://" + ips + ":" + por)
                    iplist.append(ip)
    return random.choice(iplist)

get_proxy()
```

Comment: Would you care to provide some explanation, please? Maybe one sentence on what you changed...

Comment: sir not working "Process finished with exit code 0"

Comment: The problem is that the `iplist` is not a list in the original code, it is actually **ONE** ip, so I added an definition of an `iplist` to store these `ips`, and then randomly choice one.

Comment: sir its working instead of "return random.choice(iplist)" i've used "return print(random.choice(iplist))", thank you

Comment: @scoop realm This function is return a proxy str, you should `print(get_proxy())` to see the result.